Docker ENTRYPOINT script not receiving SIGTERM
I am trying to make a container that saves data to a folder on the container linking to the host os on exit.
However, it doesn’t trigger the trapped command.
This is the ENTRYPOINT format of the Dockerfile:
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","start.sh"]

And this is start.sh:
trap 'echo "replace with command that saves data"' SIGTERM
java -jar program.jar

However, it doesn't catch the signal at all.
Keep in mind I am trying to let start.sh receive the signal and save data, not the program.

How are you starting and stopping the container?  Can you have the program directly write to the bind-mounted directory; or can you run the program directly on the host with a JVM there, so that you don't need this added complexity?

I can't run it on the folder because of some complication involving the folder naming & others. I think I got it running though.

OK, so I figured out what I was missing. The program was continuously running so the trap couldn't be triggered.
Instead I did this:
trap 'echo "replace with command that saves data"' SIGTERM
java -jar program.jar & 
while true
do
echo Waiting
echo $BGPID
sleep 2
done

Which works as the program was in parallel.
